# Install a specific Ruby on Rails version on Windows

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Normally I use:

```
gem install rails
```

I can install Rails on Windows, but by default, I guess the latest version, version 3.0.3 is installed.

So if I want to install some other version of Rails, let's say 3.0.1, how can I do it?

Answer (score 96, accepted):

Example:

```
gem install rails -v 3.0.1
```

Also, all the options for gem can be seen by running `gem -h`

A note:
If you're on *nix using [RVM](http://rvm.beginrescueend.com/) is highly recommended for Ruby management.